# Is there a way for C# Batch to consume a webService using OIDC?

Tags: c#, web-services, openid-connect

I have a C# batch that executes every hour, consuming a distant web service.

I want to add an OIDC security layer to consume this web service with an OAuth 2 OIDC-based authentication

Is there a way to use OIDC on a non-web project?

Comment: have you **tried** anything?

Comment: i'm still in the analysis Phase

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenID Connect works with even with non-web projects. Using the client credentials flow even console applications in C# can communicate with an OIDC server (like IdentityServer or Auth0) and get tokens back. client credentials flow is intended for application-to-application communication where no human user is involved.